# Phonegap asset downloader in app with remote index.html

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, download

I have a phonegap app which uses a remote url in the `loadUrl` call and I'm trying to figure out a way to download images to the device and display them in the app.

I've got a downloader working fine, storing images at file:///mnt/sdcard/.myapp, but I can't figure out how to display them from there. I suspect permission issues. I tried just using the file protocol style url for image elements and background images; neither worked. I also tried using base64 strings, but the images are relatively large and there are a lot of them so it's really slow...

Anyone have any clever ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are referring it from you HTML, but I have similar situation where my downloaded images are stored in sdcard and I use following ways to display them.

Also make sure your phone is in `Charge only` mode, and not in `Disk drive` mode.

Direct `img` tag

```
<img src="file:///mnt/sdcard/.myapp/1335801699503.png" width="100px" height="100px">
```

As a CSS property

```
<div style="background: url(file:///mnt/sdcard/.myapp/1335801699503.png) no-repeat; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you are referencing the local files from a remote index.html.